# How to change the background of a rails bootstrap app from grey to white

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason my rails app - using bootstrap - has the background always set to grey...the same colour as the jumbotron so if I want to use the jumbotron it just blends into the background. Looking at the bootstrap website the background is set to white by default. I don't think i have any css setting it to grey...can I get some advice how to change it back to white.

Thanks.

Jerome

Comment: Can you share your code? The markup of `application.html.erb` and your stylesheets would help.

Comment: Sorted it. Thanks. Didn't have require bootstrap in application.css. Thx!

Comment: @JeromeGoldstein add a custom css to change the background color.